# C++ designing containers and managing list return

Tags: c++, containers, return

I am developing a class which acts as a container for another class. In the container class I must implement a method to get all elements in the collection. My container class uses a std::deque.

Should I return a reference to the deque?
Should I return a copy of the deque? (my god tell me this is not the answer... :) )
Should I return an array?
...
What's the best practice in this context?
Thank you

Comment: Ask yourself why you need access to the internal objects outside of your container class. You might be breaking encapsulation. Perhaps you can add a method that allows you to modify each internal object by passing in a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice IMHO is to use the [iterator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) and return iterators

As far as your particular example is concerned I would do something like this:

```
class myContainer
{
public: 
   typedef std::deque<X> actual_container_type;
   typedef actual_container_type::iterator iterator;
   typedef actual_container_type::const_iterator const_iterator;
   //etc...

   iterator begin() {return cont.begin(); }
   const_iterator begin() const {return cont.begin(); }
   iterator end() {return cont.end(); }
   const_iterator end() const {return cont.end(); }

   //you may choose to also provide push_front and push_back... or whatever :)


  private:
     actual_container_type cont;
}
```

Comment: In your case the iterators you return are ones from existing STL classes. A user returning their own iterators should derive their class from std::iterator so it picks up the properties and typedefs. There is no need to do that if the iterator is a pointer.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. Now I can move better and see clearly... Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, one thing... How does the compiler know when I'm colling the iterator begin() or const_iterator begin()?

Comment: @Andry: If the function is invoked on a const object the const version will be called, otherwise the nonconst one. Don't forget that the object argument(this) of the member function also participates in overload resolution and MyContainer& and const MyContainer& are different types (for purposes of overload resolution)

Comment: Ah yes, ok, many things are getting much better now :) Well, OK I understood how references are treated in c++, but still do not understand one thing: consider to have void f(int&) and void g(const int&), Bruce Eckel in Thinking in C++ 2nd edition tells me that invoking f(1) is WRONG, while compiler do not make problems when asking for g(1). Why does this happen?

Comment: I mean, Eckel is very clear telling me that f will not accept a const object passed to it because f wants to edit it. So I assume that these behaviors happen:
-1) void f(int&) ==> if I try f(1) NOT ALLOWED, 1 is const, f is willing to edit it but won't be able to.
-2) void f(const int&) ==> if I try f(1) OK, 1 is const, f won't modify it.
-3) void f(const obj&); obj a; f(a) ==> Well, let's think about it! a is non-const but it will be cast to const obj& and, as result, f will take it but won't edit it
Well is it all right?

Comment: @Andy:  Read Stanley Lippman's excellent book called "C++ Primer". One of the first chapters will thouroughly explain this to you. The whole book is a gem. But in short, references to const T (const T&) can be bound to rvalues of type T, whereas ordinary references bind only to lvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap `begin()`, `end()`, `size()` and `operator[]` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is a common pattern in c++, :) it's noticeable I'm not an expert... :) But just one question: How does the compiler know when I'm colling the iterator begin() or const_iterator begin()?

Comment: That depends on the context, if your object is const, it will call const_iterator begin() const; Note that it's the rightmost const that gets overloaded, not the return type.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator pattern is nice but you are exposing your implementation details.  It can be abused and break your class internals.  These are all bad things for an API and you should design protection against this.

It sounds wasteful but the safest way is to return a copy of your collection as a std::vector.

Comment: But a const_iterator would provide identical output to a const_iterator on the copied std::vector anyways, right? (Unless the data was modified in the interim, but then all bets are off...) My point is that no harm could be done to the internals. Just don't expose a non-const iterator.

Comment: const_iterator is alright.  You can run into problems if you change the implementation of your collection though, ie if you change the collection to a map don't expect your iterators to work as they did.  And as you point out, modifying the data from another thread is going to invalidate the iterators, which you won't necessarily know about.  Copying is safest!